# Can Google Sheets functions name columns by their row 1 column names (price, count, etc.) rather than by column references (e.g., A, AE, etc.)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

Functions in Google Sheets get hard to understand because they reference column numbers rather than column names

```
=IF(ISBLANK(K63),"", TEXTJOIN("_",TRUE,"VO",$H63,TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,$G63,$E63),K63))
```

Is there a way to call columns by their row 1 name inside of Google Sheets functions?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Named Ranges** and set up your own nicknames:

[image]

otherwise:

```
=IF(K63="",, TEXTJOIN("_", 1, "VO", $H63, TEXTJOIN(, 1, $G63, $E63), K63))
```